# Contacts does not read properly from LDAP and/or Zimbra

Tags: mail.app, email, contacts, ldap

I can't get Contacts to work with an Open LDAP server in OSX 10.9.2, apparently regardless of the settings that I use.  I can query it from the command line, so it's definitely working.  I have also tried using the Zimbra server (`CardDAV` is disabled). Does anyone know a way to get this working, or see a problem in the settings below?

Zimbra of course uses the LDAP server for auth/contacts (apparently via a mirror).  My colleagues using Outlook have no issue getting this to work, but I can't seem to get it to go.

**LDAP**

1. Command line works against OpenLDAP w/o auth or *with* auth
2. Command line works against Zimbra server with auth
3. Not many error messages
4. Tried all scopes (base,onelevel,subtree)
5. Tried many combinations of accounts
6. Server does not use SSL

LDAP Server: *(notice the `-D` difference in the identifier & host address)*

```
# also works without authentication
ldapsearch -vLx -H ldap://ldap.company.com -b "ou=people,dc=company,dc=com" 
-D "cn=Andrew Backer,ou=people,dc=company,dc=com" -w secretpassword
```

Zimbra Server:

```
ldapsearch -vLx -H ldap://mail.company.com -b "ou=people,dc=company,dc=com" 
-D "uid=andrewbacker,ou=people,dc=company,dc=com" -w secretpassword
```

- A filter of `(objectClass=person)` works to just pull out the people
- Base and subtree queries work (e.g. without `ou=people`)

I don't get many messages in the log file, most of the time.  The few I have gotten seem to come when querying zimbra w/o a password, or when typing in the contacts search box.

```
# these two events occurred right after each other
Mail[72056]    : -[ABAddressBook save] failed.(<ABAddressBook: 0x6080000dd2d0>)
sandboxd[74206]: ([74205]) Contacts(74205) deny file-write-mode 
      /Users/andrew/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.AddressBook
#=> Full Report (head 4)
Process:         Contacts [74205]
Path:            /Applications/Contacts.app/Contents/MacOS/Contacts
Load Address:    0x1006ef000
Identifier:      com.apple.AddressBook

#permissions on that folder:  (it is empty)
drwxr-xr-x@ 2 andrew  admin   68 May 20 11:56 com.apple.AddressBook/

com.apple.preferences.internetaccounts.remoteservice[74659]: 
    An instance 0x7fd1a49d3860 of class ABLDAPSource was deallocated while key 
    value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, 
    and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint 
    on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current 
    observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7fd1a49d56b0> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7fd1a499fdd0: Observer: 0x7fd1a49c5dd0, 
    Key path: uidNext, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> 
    Context: 0x7fff8a59d43b, Property: 0x7fd1a27d3840>
)
```

** Additional Info: **

I realized now that these errors are related to this.  When I set up a new account (ldap) I get these two errors.  They both came up the last time after changing from a host name to an IP for the server.

```
secd[173]:  SecErrorGetOSStatus unknown error domain: com.apple.security.sos.error for error: 
The operation couldn’t be completed. 
    (com.apple.security.sos.error error 2 - Public Key not available - failed to register before call)
secd[173]:  securityd_xpc_dictionary_handler com.apple.sbd[71987] DeviceInCircle 
The operation couldn’t be completed. 
    (com.apple.security.sos.error error 2 - Public Key not available - failed to register before call)
```

**CardDAV**:

1. Alternates between "can't establish secure connection" and "invalid account"
2. No error messages in console
3. Tried using both ldap `dn`s above, plain user name, etc
4. CardDAV works fine with goooooooooogle
5. Gave up

I don't much care if the contacts come from Zimbra or from LDAP (of course, Zimbra is preferred since it's also the mail server).